# Aggregate data for 3 months for the current year and then transpose the uniques values of a column in R

Tags: r

I have a column that represents a date in a dataframe. I simply want to create a new dataframe that summarizes amount coulmn at ID for 3months (20140831, 20140930,20141031)
using the date column. Then transposing the Brand Column with the summarized Amount value for each. What is the best approach?

the data set is as below.

```
  ID         date       Brand     Amount
 1001   20141031    UNIBIC          9.8
 1001   20140930    UNIBIC          1.023
 1002   20140831    CITRIZINE       2.019
 1002   20140930    CITRIZINE       2.015
 1002   20141031    CITRIZINE       1.002
 1003   20140831    CHOCO           4.22
 1004   20140930    SOLOSTAR        1.007
 1004   20141030    SOLOSTAR        1.008
 1005   20140930    DOLO            1.025
```

I would like to have the Output as below

```
  ID           UNIBIC     CITRIZINE   CHOCO   SOLOSTAR      DOLO  
  1001        5.4115                
  1002                  1.678
  1003                               4.22        
  1004                                        1.039
  1005                                                    1.025
```

Any help provided from your end will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
df$Brand <- factor(df$Brand, levels=unique(df$Brand))
dcast(df, ID~Brand, value.var='Amount', mean)
#   ID UNIBIC CITRIZINE CHOCO SOLOSTAR  DOLO
#1 1001 5.4115       NaN   NaN      NaN   NaN
#2 1002    NaN  1.678667   NaN      NaN   NaN
#3 1003    NaN       NaN  4.22      NaN   NaN
#4 1004    NaN       NaN   NaN   1.0075   NaN
#5 1005    NaN       NaN   NaN      NaN 1.025
```

Or may be you can try `dcast.data.table` which would be faster

```
library(data.table) 
dcast.data.table(setDT(df), ID~Brand, value.var='Amount', mean)
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   group_by(ID, Brand) %>% 
   summarise(Amount=mean(Amount)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(Brand, Amount)
```

#### Update

If you need only `Aug`, `Sep`, and `Oct`, you could `subset` the dataset before transforming.

```
df1 <-  df[as.numeric(substr(df$date, 5,6)) %in% 8:10,]
dcast(df1, ID~Brand, value.var='Amount', mean)
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(ID = c(1001L, 1001L, 1002L, 1002L, 1002L, 1003L, 
 1004L, 1004L, 1005L), date = c(20141031L, 20140930L, 20130831L, 
 20140930L, 20141031L, 20130831L, 20130930L, 20131030L, 20140930L
 ), Brand = c("UNIBIC", "UNIBIC", "CITRIZINE", "CITRIZINE", "CITRIZINE", 
 "CHOCO", "SOLOSTAR", "SOLOSTAR", "DOLO"), Amount = c(9.8, 1.023, 
 2.019, 2.015, 1.002, 4.22, 1.007, 1.008, 1.025)), .Names = c("ID", 
 "date", "Brand", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Akrun, I would like the summarized data for 3 months(i.e, AUG, SEP, OCt 2014) for ID:1001 for UNIBIC it should be 5.41

Comment: @ akrun the summarized value for UNIBIC is only for two months hence i have put 5.4115.

Comment: @user3719979  Could you show the calculation of how you got `5.41` `mean(df$Amount[1:2])#[1] 5.4115`

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. the dataset has values from January till October 2014 but i need the data for only AUG, SEp and Oct 2014. I the case of Unibic its only for AUg and SEP so i have done a mean on  Amount to get 5.41

Comment: @user3719979  I updated the post, based on your description.  Please check.